# Value in field getting larger on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

So In Firefox when I refresh [this](http://jsbin.com/rawozeri/1) page the HEX value keeps adding up. Like this

[image]

As you can see that's not a proper HEX. It only happens in *Firefox* when you refresh *only*. Not enter the URL and press enter. Here's the code. I'm this is where the code is placed into the fields.

```
console.log("Here are all the colors that have been generated since you loaded the     page. \nAnd ignore any warnings, thats normal.");
var r = $(".r");
var g = $(".g");
var b = $(".b");
r.val(r.val() + "255");
g.val(g.val() + "255");
b.val(b.val() + "255");

function setColor(color) {
  var blackWhite = parseInt(color, 16) > 0xffffff / 2 ? 'black' : 'white';
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#" + color;
  document.body.style.color = blackWhite;
  $('input').css({
    borderColor: blackWhite,
    color: blackWhite
  });
  $('a').css({
    color: blackWhite,
    color: blackWhite
  });


  console.log("#" + color);
  $('.hex').val(color);

  function hex2rgb(hex) {
    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result ? {
  r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
  g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
  b: parseInt(result[3], 16)

    } : null;
  }
  $('.r').val(hex2rgb(color).r);
 $('.g').val(hex2rgb(color).g);
  $('.b').val(hex2rgb(color).b);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).keydown(function (e) {
   if (e.keyCode == '32') {
     setColor(Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8));
     $(".dir").css("visibility", "hidden");
   }
  });


 $('.hex').keyup(function () {
   setColor($(this).val().replace(/^#+/i, ''));
 });
});

function update() {
  var red = parseInt($(".r").val(), 10);
  var green = parseInt($(".g").val());
  var blue = parseInt($(".b").val());
  red = red || 255;
  green = green || 255;
  blue = blue || 255;
  var rgb = RGB2HTML(red, green, blue);
  $(".hex").val(rgb);
  $("body").css("background", "#" + rgb);
}

function hex(num) {
  var ret = num.toString(16);
  if (ret.length < 2) {
    ret = "0" + ret;
  }
  return ret;
}

function RGB2HTML(red, green, blue) {
  return hex(red) + hex(green) + hex(blue);
}
$(function () {
  $('.r, .g, .b').keyup(update);
  update();
});
$('.newclass').click(function () {
  $('.hex').val('');
  $('.r').val('');
  $('.g').val('');
  $('.b').val('');
  $("body").css("background", "#fff");
  $("body").css("color", "black");
  $(".hex").css("border", "3px solid black");
  $(".hex").css("color", "black");
  $(".r").css("border", "3px solid black");
  $(".r").css("color", "black");
  $(".g").css("border", "3px solid black");
  $(".g").css("color", "black");
  $(".b").css("border", "3px solid black");
  $(".b").css("color", "black");
  $("a").css("color", "black");
});
```

Comment: where is `color` set? Also it is probably a form submission that is being re-processed each time. We would need to see more code to correctly pin point the issue.

Comment: All the code was in the demo. But I will add it to the post right now. @Vector

Comment: All set. I added it @Vector

Comment: in your code `r.val(r.val() + "255");
g.val(g.val() + "255");
b.val(b.val() + "255");` you are carrying out addition, not concatenation, are you aware of this?

Comment: Yes I am aware of if @Vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your code and tested it on a local server. This seems to be a firefox bug with JSBin. It should work fine on your website. I have used the same code on `jsfiddle` and it works in forefox without any problems.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/T24y2/1/

Why are you doing this :

```
r.val(r.val() + "255");
g.val(g.val() + "255");
b.val(b.val() + "255");
```

And not this? :

```
r.val("255");
g.val("255");
b.val("255");
```